# Cascading UIPickerView in different UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uipickerview

I have two different `UIPickerView` that located in different custom `UITableViewCell`. First `UIPickerView` data loaded on page loaded. And second `pickerView` loaded after some selection is made first `pickerView`. How do I pass first selected value to second `pickerView`? I can't use cell `didSelect`, because Interaction is already been picked up by `PickerView`, thus not firing the table view `delegate`.

My code so far:

```
extension ReservationViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == ReservationCell.MakeReservation.rawValue {
            //print value --> this is not firing
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == ReservationCell.MakeReservation.rawValue {
        //print value --> this not firing
        }
    }
}

extension ReservationLocationTableViewCell: UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    //Set number of rows in components

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        return self.data.count

    }
    //Set title for each row
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        return data[row]


    }
    // Update textfield text when row is selected
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        print(data[row]) // I want to pass this value to next cell that contains another PickerView

    }
}
```

How did I pass data value to next cell?

Comment: how you will display selected value of pickerview  in tabelviewcell

Answer (score 0):

Save your selected data `data[row]` or `row` somewhere in your `ReservationViewController` first. Then you can reload your `tableView` to do logic for your second `UIPickerView`.

```
var selectedRow: Int = 0

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    print(data[row]) // I want to pass this value to next cell that contains another PickerView

    // save the row
    selectedRow = row
    // do your logic in tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```